# Oracle XMLDB import xml to db

Tags: xml, database, oracle, import

I have trouble with xml imort to XMLDB.

So, thats what i`ve done:

1. `CREATE TABLE orders OF XMLTYPE`
2. `CREATE OR REPLACE TT AS '/home/oracle/Desktop/contract_test/'(GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY TT TO superuser;)`
3. `INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (xmltype(bfilename('TT', 'contract.xml'), nls_charset_id('utf-8')));`

Finaly, i have those error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES
>   (xmltype(bfilename('TT', 'contract.xml'), nls_charset_id('utf-8')))
>   Error report - SQL Error: ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN
>   failed No such file or directory
>   22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
>   *Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
>   *Action:   See the next error message in the error stack for more detailed
>              information.  Also, verify that the file or LOB exists and that
>              the necessary privileges are set for the specified operation. If
>              the error still persists, report the error to the DBA.

I have this error at system account and "superuser" account with i made before.

Comment: If `TT` is directory you should use `CREATE DIRECTORY  TT ..`  and **not** `CREATE OR REPLACE TT ...`. see [docu](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207)

Comment: It doesent matter. Same result at both CREATE or CREATE OR REPLACE

Comment: My point was - you **don't use** the `DIRECTORY` keyword...

Comment: The most probable cause: either teh file doens't exists in the specified directory, or there is no operating system read access to the file for the oracle user.

Comment: Marmite Bomber, ah, sorry, my mistake in post. Ofcourse i use DIRECTORY keyword in oracle..

Comment: Marmite Bomber, its doing at virtual oracle machine. I dont think that there can be problem with access.
And about existing - i can easily open this file by terminal